# How to access the Provider class instances inside the class but outside the build() or functions

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider

I have to update the UI based on the Provider class instance's values. I have to access many variables from the Provider class. So,I called those variables and stored them in a variable inside the `build()`.bcz, the provider requires `context`.

After that, I paste my code into ChatGPT to resolve a problem. GPT suggests that you use `build()` for only building UI. Try to avoid additional declarations. It might cause performance issues. So,I tried to call the provider class' variable outside the `build()`. but it did not work,bcz it requires `context`. So, I want to know, is it true that the performance issues might occur as GPT said, and if yes, how can we solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can call the provider instance inside the didchangedependecies widget which allows you to use the context inside it.

Comment: Brother, My question is, how to call them outside any other method or functions.